# Any reason why I can't connect to localhost in GitLab.com CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to test some HTTP REST APIs, and for that I need to be able to have my job to listen and to make requests to itself.

In order to simulate such a scenario, I made a simple pipeline where I mount a netcat server, and then try to connect.

```
test_backend_job:
  image: debian:latest
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get --assume-yes install netcat
    - nohup nc -l localhost 5000 &
    - sleep 5
    - nc -v localhost 5000
```

If I try this on my PC, the connection is established with success. However in GitLab I get a connection refused, in any port I choose.

```
(...)
Preparing to unpack .../netcat-traditional_1.10-41.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking netcat-traditional (1.10-41.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package netcat.
Preparing to unpack .../netcat_1.10-41.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking netcat (1.10-41.1) ...
Setting up netcat-traditional (1.10-41.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /bin/nc.traditional to provide /bin/nc (nc) in auto mode
Setting up netcat (1.10-41.1) ...
$ nohup nc -l localhost 5000 &
$ sleep 5
$ nc -v localhost 5000
localhost [127.0.0.1] 5000 (?) : Connection refused
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What am I missing? This should be pretty straightforward.

**Note:** I am running this in their "cloud".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use a netcat image as a service and then run the scripts?

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-services-are-linked-to-the-job

Comment: My issue is that apparentely there are two netcat apps, one native and one from openbsd... I am using the native where I need to fix this `nohup nc -l localhost 5000 &` into this `nohup nc -l localhost -p 5000 &` (notice the -p). The openbsd one doesnt need that flag. With this change, I can now connect properly.